# I need to write an sql query to "display all the products which are having more than one category"

Tags: mysql

I have a database table which contains `productId`, `categoryId` as columns. A `productId` may have more than one category. I need to display what are the `productId`s having more than one category along with corresponding `categoryId`.

Result may look like:

```
productId      categoryId

A                C1
A                C4
B                C10
B                C6
B                C14
```

Comment: Please note that you will be more likely to get an answer to your question if you post what you've already tried, and why that did not work. Also note that from the help page on "on topic questions": "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 0):

I Think below query will help you

```
SELECT tab1.productId ,tab1.categoryId
FROM tab1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT productId,COUNT(categoryId) AS Total
FROM  tab1
GROUP BY productId
HAVING COUNT(categoryId) > 1) b ON tab1.productId = b.productId
```